# Finding a median of a collection of values in c++

Tags: c++, sorting, median

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compute Median of Values Stored In Vector - C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114797/compute-median-of-values-stored-in-vector-c)

I need to store a collection of values and then have the ability to calculate its median value.

What is the best container in c++ to store these values, and how do I find the median?

(I might also want  to be able to remove specific elements, so I am thinking set may not be the best option...)

Comment: To you want the most efficient method, or the simplest code?

Comment: @Bo and @Beta: I think what I was trying to get at...
1. Is there a built in function that calculated the median
2. What's the best container for sorting (which containers automatically sort), if not, what's the best way to sort.. MOST EFFICIENTLY, in terms of the speed. I will need to do this calculation 1000s of times.

Comment: @user620189 - Follow the link!  :-)  It shows how to put the values in a vector and sort them. The median will end up, eh, in the middle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short of any other specific requirements, you should default to a [`std::vector`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Vector.html).  You mention that you want to remove items later; this implies that you may want to consider a `std::list` instead.

To find the median, you can use [`std::nth_element`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/nth_element/), asking it to pivot on the `N/2`-th (or `(N-1)/2`-th) element.  This runs in *O(N)* time.

Comment: Maybe you need to add that the values should be sorted first (O(nlog(n))

Comment: @juan: No, because they don't need to be sorted.  If they were already sorted, then there'd be no need for an algorithm to find the median!

Comment: I stand corrected! So `nth_element` is faster because elements to either side of n don't actually have to be sorted, just less than or greater than the nth, respectively...

Comment: You missed "to be able to remove specific elements". Is not it a strong indication to use linked list instead of vector?

Comment: @Nikiton: you're right, I did miss that!