# Is there a median function in the C++ library?

Tags: c++

I am trying to calculate the median of a sorted array of numbers in C++ and I was wondering if there is a built in function in the C++ library that does this.

Comment: *"sorted array with an unknown size"* What does that mean? You need *some* way to tell where the arrays ends, and you thus know the size.

Comment: There's no median function in the C++ standard library. Related question: [Compute Median of Values Stored In Vector - C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2114797/3425536)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no need to use a function. To find the median of a list with an odd number of items, just do

```
cout << sortedArray[size/2];
```

where sortedArray is the array and size is the size of the array.
For an array with an even number, you should just do something like this

```
cout << (sortedArray[size/2] + sortedArray[(size/2) - 1])/2
```

In other words, take the average of the n/2 element and the n/2-1 element.

If you don't know the size, you need to loop through the array and count how many elements there are. Doing it with decimals is irrelevant because the size of an array is always a whole number.

Comment: What if there's an even number of elements? You'd want to take the average of the two in the middle. e.g. median of 2 4 6 8 should be 5.

Comment: For the second case, I think you want `size/2 - 1` and `size/2` as the indices.

Comment: Ok, although what should I use to declare size? I am getting an error that says size wan't declared in this scope.

Comment: size should be the size of the array. If you don't readily have it, you need to iterate through the array until the end and count how many elements there are.

Comment: @GabrieleB-David: He can get the size using the operator `sizeof` instead of iterating.

Comment: @Raindrop7 That's true, but in the end the compiler just iterates over the array to find its size so there is no significant speed improvement and when learning this stuff, it's better to know how to do these things explicitly.

Comment: @GabrieleB-David: Can a compiler iterate over elements of array without knowing its size? If so please show me?

Comment: @GabrieleB-David *"in the end the compiler just iterates over the array to find its size"* Huh? Where did you get that idea?

Comment: @Raindrop7 I misunderstood your comment. I thought you meant the size of function in the c standard library. Apologies

Comment: The principle of this answer is great - but do be aware of the possibility of [integer overflow when computing the semi-sum](https://research.googleblog.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html) when the values are very large.  Have a look at [Salvatore Ruggieri's paper](http://pages.di.unipi.it/ruggieri/Papers/semisum.pdf) for some robust algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the size of the sorted array, you can compute its median in O(1).
When the size is unknown (is it a linked list or what?), then counting the median would take O(n) on a classical computer.

Comment: Scan the list left-to-right moving the pointer to current median twice slower?