# Finding the median value of a vector using C++

Tags: c++

I'm a programming student, and for a project I'm working on, on of the things I have to do is compute the median value of a vector of int values and must be done by passing it through functions. Also the vector is initially generated randomly using the C++ random generator mt19937 which i have already written down in my code.I'm to do this using  the sort function  and vector member functions such as `.begin()`, `.end()`, and `.size()`.

I'm  supposed to make sure I find the median value of the vector and then output it

And I'm **Stuck**, below I have included my attempt. So where am I going wrong? I would appreciate if you would be willing to give me some pointers or resources to get going in the right direction.

**Code:**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
#include<random>
#include<vector>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
#include<random>

using namespace std;

double find_median(vector<double>);
double find_median(vector<double> len)
{
    {
        int i;
        double temp;
        int n=len.size();
        int mid;
        double median;
        bool swap;

        do
        {
            swap = false;
            for (i = 0; i< len.size()-1; i++)
            {
                if (len[i] > len[i + 1])
                {
                    temp = len[i];
                    len[i] = len[i + 1];
                    len[i + 1] = temp;
                    swap = true;
                }
            }
        }
        while (swap);

        for (i=0; i<len.size(); i++)
        {
            if (len[i]>len[i+1])
            {
                temp=len[i];
                len[i]=len[i+1];
                len[i+1]=temp;
            }
            mid=len.size()/2;
            if (mid%2==0)
            {
                median= len[i]+len[i+1];
            }
            else
            {
                median= (len[i]+0.5);
            }
        }
        return median;
    }
}
    int main()
    {
        int n,i;

        cout<<"Input the vector size: "<<endl;
        cin>>n;
        vector <double> foo(n);
        mt19937 rand_generator;
        rand_generator.seed(time(0));

        uniform_real_distribution<double> rand_distribution(0,0.8);
        cout<<"original vector: "<<" ";
        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            double rand_num=rand_distribution(rand_generator);
            foo[i]=rand_num;
            cout<<foo[i]<<" ";

        }
double median;
        median=find_median(foo);

        cout<<endl;

        cout<<"The median of the vector is:  "<<" ";
cout<<median<<endl;
    }
```

Comment: you don't need a function prototype if you're going to implement it before your `main` function

Comment: Im required to output my value only via the main function.(The question requires me to use a function prototype).

Comment: Your question text is oddly close to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114797/compute-median-of-values-stored-in-vector-c?rq=1

Comment: probably  median = (len[i]+len[i+1]) / 2;

Comment: The point of this question is to find out whats wrong with my code.

Comment: Start with some small fixed test-cases, e.g. `int main() { return median({0, 1, 1, 2}) != 1; }` and build up from there.

Answer (score 20):

The median is given by

```
const auto median_it = len.begin() + len.size() / 2;
std::nth_element(len.begin(), median_it , len.end());
auto median = *median_it;
```

For even numbers (size of vector) you need to be a bit more precise. E.g., you can use

```
assert(!len.empty());
if (len.size() % 2 == 0) {
    const auto median_it1 = len.begin() + len.size() / 2 - 1;
    const auto median_it2 = len.begin() + len.size() / 2;

    std::nth_element(len.begin(), median_it1 , len.end());
    const auto e1 = *median_it1;

    std::nth_element(len.begin(), median_it2 , len.end());
    const auto e2 = *median_it2;

    return (e1 + e2) / 2;

} else {
    const auto median_it = len.begin() + len.size() / 2;
    std::nth_element(len.begin(), median_it , len.end());
    return *median_it;
}
```

There are of course many different ways how we can get element `e1`. We could also use `max` or whatever we want. But this line is important because `nth_element` only places the `n`th element correctly, the remaining elements are ordered before or after this element, depending on whether they are larger or smaller. This range is *unsorted*.

This code is guaranteed to have *linear complexity on average*, i.e., `O(N)`, therefore it is asymptotically better than sort, which is `O(N log N)`.

---

Regarding your code:

```
    for (i=0; i<len.size(); i++){
        if (len[i]>len[i+1])
```

This will not work, as you access `len[len.size()]` in the last iteration which does not exist.

Comment: Nice; better than my answer. Upvoted especially now you've done the bit for even numbers.

Comment: @steve Do you agree now?

Comment: I wouldn't write the code like this. Using a variable would be so much cleaner. In addition your statement about n log n is incorrect. It uses a partition algorithm, which guarantees o(n) run time complexity as it does not need to sort all the elements, only the nth element.

Comment: You need to reread my argument. I say it is on average O(N), whil esort is O(N log N) which is exactly what you say - I'll try to clarify this point. Of course I could write it differently using a variable, but I don't think this is necessary because this is not the main focus of the question.

Comment: It is guaranteed to be O(n).

Comment: For pre-C++17 It is guaranteed to be O(n) *on average*. Check section 25.4.2 in the standard (document n3690, [avg.nth.element]). It may be O(n) in most implementations, but there will be no guarantee.

Comment: I don't think that [nth_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) is the correct choice, given that it doesn't guarantee that the first elements in the range would be sorted, but only that _"all of the elements before this new nth element are less than or equal to the elements after the new nth element."_. See [here](https://ideone.com/fDyNNi), for example.

Comment: Thanks @Bob__, very good point! I just edited my code. Do you agree now? Still i think that `nth_element` is the correct choice, because of asymptocally better performance. Given a reasonable large vector, this will be faster than `sort` very soon (I would be suprrized if there were a large constant in `nth_element`).

Comment: Yes, I agree. It should be faster too, on average.

Comment: For something that works in both even and odd cases, you have `auto index1 = (len.size() - 1) / 2; auto index2 = len.size() / 2;`.  If they are equal, then the averaging step *could* be skipped, for efficiency, but the result is correct either way.  Don't forget to check `.size() > 0` in any implementation!

Comment: After the second call to `std::nth_element` , median_it1 might not be pointing to the original value.

Answer (score 5):

```
std::sort(len.begin(), len.end());
double median = len[len.size() / 2];
```

will do it. You might need to take the average of the middle two elements if `size()` is even, depending on your requirements:

```
0.5 * (len[len.size() / 2 - 1] + len[len.size() / 2]);
```

Comment: not you might, you have to. This is how the median is defined.

Comment: `std::nth_element` has better complexity than `std::sort`.

Comment: Indeed, I'll leave this up anyway for good measure: have upvoted the other answer to set it on its way.

Comment: I think that your solution is better then using [nth_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) which doesn't  guarantee that the first elements would be sorted, but only that _"all of the elements before this new nth element are less than or equal to the elements after the new nth element."_. See [here](https://ideone.com/fDyNNi), for example.

Comment: @Bob__ Is that not the requirement for the median?

Comment: @pingul As far as I know, _"A median is only defined on ordered one-dimensional data"_ (wiki)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to do everything at once, you should start with simple test cases and work upwards:

```
#include<vector>

double find_median(std::vector<double> len);

// Return the number of failures - shell interprets 0 as 'success',
// which suits us perfectly.
int main()
{
    return find_median({0, 1, 1, 2}) != 1;
}
```

This already fails with your code (even after fixing `i` to be an unsigned type), so you could start debugging (even 'dry' debugging, where you trace the code through on paper; that's probably enough here).

I do note that with a smaller test case, such as `{0, 1, 2}`, I get a crash rather than merely failing the test, so there's something that really needs to be fixed.

Let's replace the implementation with one based on [overseas's answer](/a/42791986):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>

double find_median(std::vector<double> len)
{
    if (len.size() < 1)
        return std::numeric_limits<double>::signaling_NaN();

    const auto alpha = len.begin();
    const auto omega = len.end();

    // Find the two middle positions (they will be the same if size is odd)
    const auto i1 = alpha + (len.size()-1) / 2;
    const auto i2 = alpha + len.size() / 2;

    // Partial sort to place the correct elements at those indexes (it's okay to modify the vector,
    // as we've been given a copy; otherwise, we could use std::partial_sort_copy to populate a
    // temporary vector).
    std::nth_element(alpha, i1, omega);
    std::nth_element(i1, i2, omega);

    return 0.5 * (*i1 + *i2);
}
```

Now, our test passes.  We can write a helper method to allow us to create more tests:

```
#include <iostream>
bool test_median(const std::vector<double>& v, double expected)
{
    auto actual = find_median(v);
    if (abs(expected - actual) > 0.01) {
        std::cerr << actual << " - expected " << expected << std::endl;
        return true;
    } else {
        std::cout << actual << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
}

int main()
{
    return test_median({0, 1, 1, 2}, 1)
        +  test_median({5}, 5)
        +  test_median({5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2}, 1.5);
}
```

Once you have the simple test cases working, you can manage more complex ones.  Only then is it time to create a large array of random values to see how well it scales:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <functional>
#include <random>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::vector<double> foo;

    const int n = argc > 1 ? std::stoi(argv[1]) : 10;
    foo.reserve(n);

    std::mt19937 rand_generator(std::time(0));
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> rand_distribution(0,0.8);
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(foo), n, std::bind(rand_distribution, rand_generator));

    std::cout << "Vector:";
    for (auto v: foo)
        std::cout << ' ' << v;

    std::cout << "\nMedian = " << find_median(foo) << std::endl;
}
```

(I've taken the number of elements as a command-line argument; that's more convenient in my build than reading it from `cin`).  Notice that instead of *allocating* `n` doubles in the vector, we simply *reserve* capacity for them, but don't create any until needed.

For fun and kicks, we can now make `find_median()` generic.  I'll leave that as an exercise; I suggest you start with:

```
typename<class Iterator>
auto find_median(Iterator alpha, Iterator omega)
{
    using value_type = typename Iterator::value_type;

    if (alpha == omega)
        return std::numeric_limits<value_type>::signaling_NaN();
}
```

Comment: This might not appear to be an answer, but I think that a lesson in debugging will be more useful than merely spoon-feeding a correct implementation.  I hope you agree, and find this useful!

Comment: @Downvoter, what's wrong?  Question is specifically asking for advice, not just working code.

Comment: Very interesting. I see that you have used a signaling NaN of the type `value_type` in the (partial) generic function too. Wouldn't be better using the (maybe different) return type (or throwing an exception)? I mean, even if iterators to `int`s are passed to the function, one still probably expects a floating point number as return type and integers have no signaling NaNs. Also, I'm wondering if you used `std::time` to be closer to OP code or if you were more concerned about `std::random_device` beeing deterministic.

Comment: I kept `std::time` to be consistent with the question - `random_device` is probably more idiomatic.  The choice to return a NaN from when passed an empty collection was fairly arbitrary, I'm afraid - throwing a `std::range_error` seems equally valid to me.