# What's the most efficient way to extract min, max & median from a vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, median

Given a `vector<T> vec{...}` what's the best way to extract its minimum, maximum and median assuming T is one of the numeric types? I know of [`std::nth_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) as well as [`std::minmax_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) but they seem to do redundant work if called one after another.

The best idea I came up with so far is to just call std::nth_element 3 times one after another. But this still needs 3N comparisons, right? Is there any way to reuse the partial sorting done in previous iterations?

Comment: The most efficient way will be to manually loop and calculate all at the same time.

Comment: @freakish How would you get a median by iterating over elements?

Comment: It doesn't solve the median problem, but the Standard Library does provide [`std::minmax_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element). Perhaps you could model your own algorithm on this - finding the median will involve checking every element anyway, so it is reasonably straightforward to extend a median algorithm to also return min/max.

Comment: `std::partial_sort()`?

Comment: @DanielLangr right, so median can be solved recursively and so can min/max. You can do it in one go I think. So not literally "loop" but equivalent linear time.

Comment: Relevant question: [What is the right approach when using STL container for median calculation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1719070/580083).

Comment: `std::nth_element`, then `std::min_element` in the left half and `std::max_element` in the right one.

Comment: Fastest way might be to `std::sort` the entire array, and pick the values after that.

Comment: @Evg: Indeed, you can extract the median with a partition as your comment (which I've converted to an answer) states.

Comment: @DanielLangr, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect

Comment: Is there a specific reason it needs to be "the most efficient"? If not, just go with the simplest, most readable solution to start off with, and you can worry about optimizing this if the need arises.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `std::nth_element` to partition which yields the median, then `std::min_element` in the left half and `std::max_element` in the right one.

If you need it to be faster than that then roll your own version based on `std::nth_element`.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to specify a custom comparison for `std::nth_element`, which captures the min and max.  It will likely end up doing a lot more comparisons and branches, so this might be slower on some specific hardware, possibly depending on how much of your data is cached etc., so - as always - benchmark if you've reason to care, but for a non-empty `vector` `a` the technique looks like this:

```
int min = a[0], max = a[0];
std::nth_element(a.begin(), a.begin() + n, a.end(),
    [&](int lhs, int rhs) {
        min = std::min(min, std::min(lhs, rhs));
        max = std::max(max, std::max(lhs, rhs));
        return lhs < rhs;
    });
```

For what little it's worth, on my (~10yo i5-660) HTPC using GCC 7.4 with 1 million random `int`s between 0 and 1000, `nth_element` takes about 36% longer with the min/max comparison than without.

Comment: You are assuming that `std::nth_element` will check all elements at least once. That's reasonable, but technically not guaranteed.

Comment: @BiagioFesta: interesting point; not guaranteed by the language spec, but I think it'd be logically impossible for it to work otherwise...?

Comment: Sure, there are some proofs in Theoretical Computer Science regarding the complexity of algorithms. However, the C++ standard does not even specify which algorithm is used to implement `std::nth_element`. If I had to write production code, I would implement the full algorithm by myself.

Comment: @BiagioFesta: correctness of this code is different from its time complexity.  I'd say it's self evident that it would be literally impossible for `nth_element` to rearrange the input data as it's required to do without invoking the provided comparison functor *at least* once for every element, but you're right that when it invokes it more than once it may adversely performance / can't predict how badly when implementation is opaque; but at worst it'll double the comparisons so no big-*O* change.  Can measure though, and that will give you a sense for whether it's worth worrying about.

Comment: As you are calculating (lhs<rhs), you might be faster to store this as the first step, and then replace the inner min/max with the trinary operator this. i.e. `min = std::min(min, (ret?lhs:rhs);`

Comment: @CSM: yeah, likely - lots of things you could try, e.g. `std::minmax`; there's also the branchless bit hacks for min (`y ^ ((x ^ y) & -(x < y));`) and max (`x ^ ((x ^ y) & -(x < y))`) - what's best will likely vary with CPU.   My main point is that `nth_element`'s comparison argument's usable for this.

Comment: 1 less comparison: `auto[low, high] = std::minmax(lhs, rhs); if (low < min) min = low; if (high > max) max = high; return rhs != low;`

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk: yup - I mentioned `minmax` in my comment above yours - wasn't noticeably faster on my CPU though, did you benchmark it to see if it was faster on your CPU?  by how much?  What's your CPU?  And `if (low < min) min = low;` didn't buy me anything over `std::min` - from memory, godbolt showed GCC 8.2 using cmovle either way.

Comment: @TonyDelroy Your assertion about correctness is valid only for the parts of the compare function that actually affect the final arrangement of the elements. Although not likely with any of the current implementations, in theory the compiler might recognize that your heavyweight functor is no different from the default "less than" comparison for the purposes of the algorithm, and optimize it away completely. 
Another "smart" compiler might decide that it needs to pre-calculate and somehow cache the results of the comparison for all possible values (it's not that much for an 8bit integer).

Comment: Just a note about 36% overhead mentioned in the answer. Starting from C++11, for simple types it would be good to use the initializer list form of `std::min` and `std::max`, something like the following `min = std::min( { min, std::min( { lhs, rhs } ) } );`. The point is `std::min(a,b)` returns a reference, and it's difficult for compilers to optimize it efficiently. OTOH  `std::min({a,b})` returns a value (not a reference) which can be easily optimized. BTW the same is true for `std::minmax`.